# how to create a pen that is the same color as that of a solid brush?

Tags: winapi, brush, pen

I would like to get the color (colorref) of a SolidBrush to create a pen of the same color, using only Windows API functions (no dot net and stuff like that) using C/C++/Asm/Delphi, etc.

If it helps, this is what I'm trying to accomplish: I've drawn a curve using PolyLine in a resizable window.

Letting Windows clear the background every time the window is resized causes a very noticeable amount of flicker.  To reduce the flicker to a minimum, I can get the background brush that Windows is using to clear the window (GetClassLongPr) and, create a pen of that same color to redraw just the curve with that pen, effectively erasing it without clearing the entire client area (which is what causes the flicker.)  Of course, I cannot create that pen unless I find a way to get the colorref from the brush handle returned by GetClassLongPtr.

I can't figure out how to create a pen that is of the color used by the solid brush windows uses to erase the client area.

NOTE: I am aware that another way of solving the flicker problem is to create a clipping region to cause just the curve to be erased but, region handling is much slower than simply redrawing the curve with a pen set to the background color.

After this long story, the question is: how do I create a pen that is the same color as that of the solid brush used to erase the window client area ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the solid brush parameters with [GetObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) into a [LOGBRUSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-taglogbrush) structure, then you use [CreatePen()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createpen) to create the Pen.

The idea however to avoid flickering is to use double buffering: Do not draw to the DC you get from GetDC(), but to a memory DC. Do not use WM_ERASEBKGND to erase the background, process WM_ERASEBKGND and return nonzero without doing anything, erase it in the WM_PAINT instead. Create the memory DC with [CreateCompatibleDC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatibledc) then use [BitBlt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) to transfer your drawing to the actual DC.

All this if at all using GDI anyway, do prefer Direct2D nowadays.

Comment: @ Michael: thank you very much!  after I saw your answer, I should have thought of that but, obviously I didn't.  I think the advice you offered is good, in this particular case, I am interested in speed and, I can't think of a faster way of erasing the parts on the screen that need to be gone.  You are correct, I am definitely erasing while processing WM_PAINT.